# Average values for same key rows excluding certain columns in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a table that has a certain subset of columns as a record-key.
Record keys might have duplicates e.g several rows might have same key, but different values. I want to average values for such same-key row into one row. But some columns have numbers that represent categories and I want to exclude them from averaging and rather pick a random value.

As an example consider this table with keys `k1` and `k2`, numerical value `v1` and categorical-int value `id`

```
k1 | k2 | v1 | id
1  | 2  | 4  | 100
1  | 3  | 2  | 200
1  | 2  | 8  | 300
1  | 2  | 2  | 400
```

I want the output to be

```
k1 | k2 | v1 | id
1  | 2  |14/3| 100 (or 300 or 400)
1  | 3  | 2  | 200
```

Currently I have a code to average values accross same-key columns:

```
g = table.groupby(primary_keys)
s = g.sum()
table = s.div(g.count(), axis=0)
```

but I do not know to extend it to exclude categorical columns (say I know what they are) and pick random value for categoricals

Comment: How you get 7 for average of 4+8+2?

Comment: @WeNYoBen yeah sorry mistake.. I initially thought of creating just two rows for same key lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way

```
df.groupby(['k1','k2']).agg({'v1':'mean','id':lambda x : x.sample(1)})
             v1   id
k1 k2               
1  2   4.666667  100
   3   2.000000  200
```